# How to set web template variable to a dynamic html&golang code?

Tags: go, web, web-frameworks, go-gin

I have two web page on golang and I want to embed this pages codes to {{.content}} variable (defined in templates/main.html) being with dynamic according to the coming requests.

For example if the guest enter the userregister page I want to the {{.content}} variable will be userregister codes otherwise userprofile codes.

templates/userregister.html page codes;

```
{{ define "userregister" }}
   ...
   {{.specialmessage}}
   ...
{{ end }}
```

templates/userprofile.html page codes;

```
{{ define "userprofile" }}
   ...
   {{.specialmessage}}
   ...
{{ end }}
```

templates/main.html;

```
{{ define "main" }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
    {{ template "head" . }}
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            {{ template "header" . }}
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="col-12 col-md-2 p-0">
                    {{ template "leftmenu" . }}
                </nav>
                <div class="container-fluid col-12 col-md-10">


                    {{.content}}


                </div>
            </div>
            {{ template "footer" . }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

The userregister page controller;

```
func PgUserRegister(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK,"main", gin.H{
        "pgETitle": "User Register page",
        "specialmessage": "You are on the userregister page.",

        "content": template.ParseFiles("userregister.html"),
    })
}
```

The userprofile page controller;

```
func PgUserProfile(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK,"main", gin.H{
        "pgETitle": "User Profile",
        "specialmessage": "You are on the userprofile page.",

        "content": template.ParseFiles("userprofile.html"),
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse all templates when starting the router.

```
router.LoadHTMLFiles("templates/main.html", "templates/userregister.html", "templates/userprofile.html")
```

Then in your handler add to the `gin.H{ ... }` expression a boolean variable, e.g. `"isLoggedIn"`, and then in your main template use an `if-else` [action](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) together with the `template` action.

```
{{ if .isLoggedIn }}
    {{ template "userprofile" . }}
{{ else }}
    {{ template "userregister" . }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mkopriva I have a lot of pages for this situation how can I make like it {{ template .pgVariable . }}                               #### pgVariable is the string variable contains page name?

Comment: That's not possible, if you look at the documentation on actions linked above you'll see that the argument must be a *literal* string containing the name of a template.

Comment: @Hakan do you have a lot of templates where you need to switch between these two specific templates? Or do you have a lot of templates where you need to switch between *different* templates, not just userprofile and userregister?

Comment: Actually; I have a lot of template pages but I posted my question being two template pages to simplify the problem. I have about 10 different pages (I am not sure yet at now), Do I have to control the template pages with if statement one by one?

Comment: Maybe rethink how you structure those templates, instead of attempting to render everything from main.html, each template would have a `template` action on top and bottom to render that content that is shared by all of them.